# How do I make "Groups" the default view for my contacts?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, contacts, contact-groups

I am using the default contacts app that came with my Android 4.04 device.  When I open the Contact app, there are 4 tabs. Phone, Groups, Contacts, and Favorites and by default it opens the Contacts.  Is there a way (a setting) to opening the  "Groups" view as default instead?

**If not** is there a another compatible Contact management application that can be recommended to give me more control over groups etc.  The primary purpose of this question is to answer about the settings, not to provide me with a long list iof Apps.

Thanks in advance